# How to understand the comparative structure “as … as …” and why isn't it “as … like …”?

Tags: comparative-constructions, as, as-like

“As” can be used with the meaning of “in the role of”. “Like” can be used to compare a thing with an other thing. But the sentence “I am as strong as an elephant.” doesn't mean that I'm in the role of an elephant. An alternative formulation of the sentence could be “I am srong like an elephant.”, which features the comparative “like”. What is the meaning of the first “as” and what is the meaning of the second “as”? I am ecpecially interested in the difference of the meanings of the second “as” and a comparative “like” because I'd like to know if “as … like …” is possible or why it isn't possible.

Comment: The first "as" is a degree adverb. The second is a preposition with a comparative clause reduced to just a noun phrase as it's complement. With "as" as the governor, you can't also have "like".

Comment: "I am as strong as an elephant" OR "I am strong, like an elephant".

Comment: @BillJ What is a governor as it is used in that comment and why can't I have “like” with it? Also, why isn't that comment an answer?